# Magento - REST API not found - at localhost/magento2/api/rest

Tags: apache, xampp, magento2

Using windows 8 - XAMPP-  Not able to find rest api in magento2 installation on localhost - need solution - I configured and rewritten URL's in httpd.conf - still not able to access rest api - please help

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2"> 
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
     AllowOverride All 
     Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Show us the relevant rewrite rules you have tried

Comment: <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Or let me know if I am missing anything to configure APACHE - XAMPP - configurations

Comment: Is https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess present in your C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2 directory? What response do you get from magento? Is it an Apache 404 page or magento's handled 404 page?

Comment: @jedifans - Yes - I do have .htaccess file located at this path - and I m getting magento's handled 404 page - saying "Whoops, our bad..."